# Riccati differential equation $y'=x^2+y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=x^2+y^2$$ I know, that this is a kind of Riccati equation, but is it possible to solve it with only simple methods? Thank you

Comment: Are exact equations simple enough? That's what I'd try.

Comment: Looking at the [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%3D+y%5E2+%2B+x%5E2) this doesn't look promising.

Comment: @nbubis Implicitly it could be easy.

Comment: @GitGud - always happy to be proven wrong :)

Comment: @nbubis I can't be arsed $\ddot \smile$, not until the OP let's me know wether it is worth trying to transform it in an exact equation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can be solved (or, rather, transformed into a recognizable form) using simple methods, but the result can only be expressed in terms of special functions.

---

Namely, let us write $\displaystyle y=-\frac{v'}{v}$, then $\displaystyle y'=-\frac{v''}{v}+\frac{v'^2}{v^2}$ so that the equation becomes *linear*:
$$v''+x^2v=0.\tag{1}$$
If we further introduce 
$$v(x)=\sqrt{x}\cdot f\left(\text{$\frac{x^2}{2}$}\right),\tag{2}$$
 then (1) transforms into a particular case of the [Bessel equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for $f(t)$:
$$t^2f''+tf'+\left(t^2-\frac{1}{16}\right)f=0.$$
It has the general solution
$$f(t)=C_1 J_{1/4}(t)+C_2J_{-1/4}(t).\tag{3}$$
Substituting this into (2), we find $v(x)$, and then $y(x)$ is given by its logarithmic derivative. Clearly, $y(x)$ will depend only on the ratio $C_1/C_2$ (instead of $C_1$, $C_2$ separately). This ratio plays the role of integration constant for the initial first order equation $y'=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your support.
Greetings Eu2718

Comment: This book is very helpful ---> Handbook of Differential Equations. Daniel Zwillinger. Academic Press 1997.